# Jtable, JScrollPane, JFrame issues

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jframe, jscrollpane

I am new to Java AWT. I want to draw a treetable (i.e. table with expandable rows) inside a JScrollpane which in turn is inside a JFrame.

By default I want to set the size of the frame to some fixed size and table inside should occupy the frame completely. This is because only when I set the frame to certain size, all cells of the table are rendered sufficiently large enough and there is no need to expand the frame to see data inside cells.

But I am not able to do this. Mostly, the table occupies only a small portion of the frame and about half of the frame remains empty. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like a layout problem. Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows your current approach. Also consider an `Outline` view, illustrated [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/4447/6692).

Answer (score 0):

assuming your `JFrame` is named `frame` and your table is called `table`, try using this:

```
frame.setSize(table.getPreferredSize());
frame.pack();
```